# Cron Job every 10 seconds with Node-Cron

Tags: node.js, express, cron

I am using to Node-Cron run a cron job on every 10 seconds. but it seems like there is a issue with node-cron. https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron#cron-ranges

i made a request at `04:28:34` but the script started at `4:28:40`(should start at `04:28:44`)

i made a request at `04:48:58` but the script started at `04:49:00` (should start at `04:49:08`)

i made a request at `05:03:45` but the script started at `05:03:50` (should start at `04:49:08`)

below is my code to execute this task.

```
router.post('/secret', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Post request!');
    console.log('Start At:' + getUTCDateTime());

    function getUTCDateTime() {

        var date = new Date();
        var dateUTC = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours(), date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds());
        var hour = dateUTC.getHours();
        hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
        var min = dateUTC.getMinutes();
        min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;
        var sec = dateUTC.getSeconds();
        sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
        var year = dateUTC.getFullYear();
        var month = dateUTC.getMonth() + 1;
        month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
        var day = dateUTC.getDate();
        day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; // format: 2015-04-10 11:40:50

    }

    function getEndDateTime(startAt, callback) {

        var date = new Date(startAt);
        date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + parseInt(callback));
        var sec = date.getSeconds();
        sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
        var hour = date.getHours();
        hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
        var min = date.getMinutes();
        min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
        var day = date.getDate();
        day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; // format: 2015-04-10 11:40:50

    }

    function getStartDateTime(startAt, callback) {

        var date = new Date(startAt);
        date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() - parseInt(callback));
        var sec = date.getSeconds();
        sec = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
        var hour = date.getHours();
        hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;
        var min = date.getMinutes();
        min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
        var day = date.getDate();
        day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; // format: 2015-04-10 11:40:50

    }

    function callBackUrl(url, data){
        var request = require('request');

        request.post(
            url,
            {form: {data: data}},
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body)
                }
            }
        );

    }

    var startAt = req.body.startAt;
    var callback = req.body.callback;
    var endAt = req.body.endAt; //2015-05-15 11:23:50
    var data = req.body.data;
    if (callback == "" || endAt == "" || data == "")
        res.end('Params cannot be empty: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    if (getUTCDateTime() >= endAt)
        res.end('Param "endAt" is invalid: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); //to get the JSON object of the string


    var callbackUrl1 = 'http://qa.www.com/index.php/api/default/test/id/1';
    var callbackUrl2 = 'http://qa.www.com/index.php/api/default/test/id/2';
    //cronStartAt = '0 */' + callback + ' * * * *'; // only every 1 minute
    cronStartAt = '*/' + callback + ' * * * * *'; // only every 1 minute
    var nowCount = 0;
    var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
    var cron = new CronJob(cronStartAt, function () {
        nowCount++;
        var tmpStartAt = getStartDateTime(getUTCDateTime(), callback);
        var tmpEndAt = getUTCDateTime();
        //var tmpStartAt = getUTCDateTime();
        //var tmpEndAt = getEndDateTime(tmpStartAt, callback);
        //console.log(tmpStartAt + ' ' + tmpEndAt);
        jsonObject.startAt = tmpStartAt;
        jsonObject.endAt = tmpEndAt;
        data = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

        callBackUrl(callbackUrl1, data);
        if (getUTCDateTime() >= endAt) {
            cron.stop();
            console.log('stopped at: ' + getUTCDateTime());
            console.log('now count: ' + nowCount);
        }
    }, function () {
        /* This function is executed when the job stops */
        // on crone stop another http call with submitted post data
        callBackUrl(callbackUrl2, data);
    }, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');

    cron.start();
    console.log("Post body: %j", req.body);
    res.end('Body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

});
```

Comment: what value is in `callback`? also how do you measure when job was executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a cron job run every 'x' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086565/can-a-cron-job-run-every-x-seconds)

Answer (score 88):

This worked for me -

```js
    cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", function() {
      console.log("running a task every 10 second");
    });
```

Hope this helps someone.

Reference - https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004224494-Cron-time-string-format

Comment: Note to self: Unlike regular cron, [node-cron has an optional *seconds* specifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron#cron-syntax).